# How to match rows in target dataset (y) with rows in pared-down predictor dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, validation, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

I am working on a problem where I am supposed to use Random Forests to determine which 1000 establishments should be audited (i.e., which 1000 are most likely to fail an audit). I have created a DataFrame that includes what the model determined to be the 1000 riskiest establishments in the validation set (`riskiest_preds`), and for comparison, I have a DataFrame that includes a 1000 establishments chosen at random from the validation set (`random_preds`). These DataFrames do not include the establishments' true classes, which are stored in `y_validate`. I need to find out what proportion of cases `[i]` in `riskiest_preds` and `random_preds` *actually* fail the audit (`y_validate[i]=1`).

What's stumping me is that `y_validate` has over 3,000 cases (rows), so I don't know how to correctly match up the subsets of `X_validate` to their corresponding targets. Once there, how exactly would I count the proportion of values in the Series (`y_validate` is a Series) that =1?

**Extra info:**

If it's useful to know, I selected the 1000 riskiest establishment by using `RF_model.predict_proba(X_validate)`, concatenating the results onto a copy of X_validate (`X_validate_copy`), and then creating a new DataFrame `riskiest_preds` like this:

`riskiest_preds = X_validate_copy.nlargest(1000, ["RF Probability Fail"], keep='first')`

**SOLUTION FOUND!**

```
FailCount = 0

risky_index = riskiest_preds.index

for index in list(risky_index):
    if y_validate[index]==1:
        FailCount += 1

true_prop_fail = FailCount/1000 
## true_prop_fail = .618

FailCount_random = 0

random_index = random_preds.index

for index in list(random_index):
    if y_validate[index]==1:
        FailCount_random += 1

true_prop_fail_random = FailCount_random/1000 
## true_prop_fail_random = .215
```